# catching and re-throwing exceptions in c++

Tags: c++, exception, managed

I am a java developer trying to maintain some very old c++ code (still have to use vs2010 to compile).

I am at home trying to understand exceptions without the ability to test stuff, so sorry if this question is stupid.

Can you throw an exception in a low level function and just catch it at the top, or does it have to be caught and re-thrown at every level?

This is complicated by the fact i am writing native code, calling managed code, calling c#, calling my java rest resource.  So are there any levels in there I absolutely have to catch and convert then re-throw.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: as Jesper has answered the first half, can my native code handle system::exception?

Comment: " without the ability to test stuff" of course you can test http://ideone.com/nAwbt2.

Comment: _"are there any levels in there I absolutely have to catch and convert then re-throw"_ yes when you cross an ABI / language boundary.

Comment: Be very careful with throwing exceptions. Unless the code in between the throw site and the catch site was written with exception safety in mind (RAII and such), you can very easily mess up the programs state. It's not as simple as it is in Java.

Comment: @bolov oops just spotted link

Comment: There are plenty of online compilers you can use to test stuff - I really like this one: https://godbolt.org and http://ideone.com is another.

Comment: @Richard-Critten, sorry to be so dense are each of the layers I mentioned language boundarys?

Comment: @StoryTeller thanks that was really usefull, I had tried using try... finally and that hadn't worked

Comment: Yes - you will need to catch the C++ exception and translate it into a result/exception suitable for the layer above.  For example if you are using Java (via JNI) to call C++ you would catch the C++ exception and before returning to Java use JNI throw an appropriate JAVA  exception, then return from the C++ code to Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Can you throw an exception in a low level function and just catch it at the top" - yes.

"does it have to be caught and re-thrown at every level?" - no.